# Visual studio release - view asm for a line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, release

How can I view the asm code for a line with VS2010 in release mode? I want to see the full-optimized version but I can't step to it (no breakpoints).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Project configuration -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Assembler Output

Comment: '/FaRelease' not allowed with multiple source files

Comment: @David Kernin add a trailing '/' to the "ASM List Location".

Answer (score 0):

You can enable generating debug info in C++ and linker tabs overriding configuration defaults.

Then you can set breakpoints and inspect assembly easily in debugger like for debug build. single-stepping may be hindeed by optimisations, but that should be tolerable.

Alternatively you can ask output of asm, code+asm files, see output file settings.